# put Google line chart in Leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization, leaflet

I'm trying to insert a Google line chart into a standalone Leaflet popup. I have the chart generation code in the header as instructed [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart), and then I put the div element in the popup.

```
var popup = L.popup()
  .setLatLng([51.5, -0.09])
  .setContent('<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 400px; height: 200px"></div>')
  .openOn(mymap);
```

This just creates an empty 400x200 popup. I'm pretty sure that the problem arises because the chart generation script can't find the div element because it doesn't exist yet, but I don't know how to fix it. I tried moving the script after the declaration of the popup, but that didn't do anything. How can I display the chart in the popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try structuring the code similar to the following snippet...

1) load google charts before anything else

2) then load other stuff you need

3) then try opening the popup

```
// run this before anything else on the page
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: initPage,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function initPage() {
  // do normal start up stuff here
  // ...

  // open the popup
  var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng([51.5, -0.09])
    .setContent('<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 400px; height: 200px"></div>')
    .openOn(mymap);

  drawChart();
}

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows([
    ['Mushrooms', 3],
    ['Onions', 1],
    ['Olives', 1],
    ['Zucchini', 1],
    ['Pepperoni', 2]
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('curve_chart');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
  chart.draw(data);
}
```