# repeatedly loading Google charts in Leaflet popups

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization, leaflet

I'm following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353488/put-google-line-chart-in-leaflet-popup) to insert a Google chart in a Leaflet popup. It works, but only if I explicitly close one popup before opening another one. If I open a second popup before closing the first, then the graph in the second popup just flickers and disappears. How can I correctly load multiple graphs in a row without explicitly closing each popup window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create unique Ids for the charts in each popup, so that when you refer to them they won't affect the others.  I'm doing that here by creating each new chart as "curve_chart1", "curve_chart2" etc. by using a variable called `popupId`.

You haven't included code so I'm assuming that it looks much like the example you linked to:

```
// run this before anything else on the page
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: initPage,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function initPage() {
  // do normal start up stuff here
  // ...

  var popupId = 1;
  var chartId = "curve_chart" + popupId;

  // open the popup
  var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng([51.5, -0.09])
    .setContent('<div id="' + chartId + '" style="width: 400px; height: 200px"></div>')
    .openOn(mymap);

  popupId++; // change the Id for the next popup

  drawChart(chartId);
}

function drawChart(elem) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows([
    ['Mushrooms', 3],
    ['Onions', 1],
    ['Olives', 1],
    ['Zucchini', 1],
    ['Pepperoni', 2]
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById(elem);
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
  chart.draw(data);
}
```

Comment: When I do that, the new chart is momentarily shown in the old popup before closing, and then the new popup is blank. I've added my code above.

Comment: If you want to set up a fiddle or plunker I'll take a look

Comment: The problem is you're setting `var chartId = "curve_chart" + popupId` too early (at the top), so it never changes value.  It needs to be next to the open popup code. Here's the updated Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ggLxv440/2/

Comment: FYI: I also saw an error when I opened your fiddle "Error: Container is not defined" in the browser console