# Attach Google Charts on Leaflet Popup

Tags: leaflet, google-visualization

I tried to attach a google chart on the popup of a layer in Leaflet by followed this [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353488/put-google-line-chart-in-leaflet-popup). However, I keep getting this error:

> "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Container is not defined"

Here is my javascript function that I use to bind the popup:

```
function layer_name(feature, layer) {
  //...
  var popupContent = L.popup().setContent('<div id="chart_div" align = "center">1</div>')

  layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {maxHeight: 400});
}
```

When I tried setting

```
<div id="chart_div" align = "center">1</div>
```

as just an HTML element there is no error raised.

I have also define the chart to be drawn at the very beginning of the script as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load Charts and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Draw the pie chart for follower chart when Charts is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that draws the bar
  function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Title', 'Value'],
        ['A', 317],
        ['B', 148],
        ['C', 67],
        ['D', 27],
        ['E', 23]
        ]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data);
    }

</script>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your HTML Element `chart_div` is not created until the popup is open. But you try to init the chart on the not created HTML Element.

Call `drawChart()` after the popup is opened.

Update your layer_name function and add the `openpopup` event to the layer. It will called when you open the popup.

```
function layer_name(feature, layer) {
  //...
  var popupContent = L.popup().setContent('<div id="chart_div" align="center">1</div>')

  layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {maxHeight: 400});
  layer.on('popupopen',function(e){
    drawChart();
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! But my new problem is that if drawChart() is only called after the popup is opened, sometimes the chart will not appear for the first time the popup is opened. Sometimes it does appear on the first time tho..

Comment: when do you use the `google.charts.load` statement? is it also part of the popup? or the page that opens the popup?

Comment: @JacklynLim you can try to add the chart first to a hidden element, so all is loaded on start and when the popup is opened you call `drawChart()` or you copy the hidden elment into your popup

Comment: @WhiteHat call the `google.charts.load` in the main script function. It should be loaded before a popup  is opened. Also don't call `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`this is not necessary

Comment: I was asking OP, since they're still having issues. and you shouldn't [draw the chart in a hidden container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613423/5090771).